# React Maximum Callstack when adding component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list component that is getting information from a local json file if I do something like the following everything works as expected.

```
import React from 'react';
import caseStudies from './case-studies.json';

import CaseStudyItem from './case-study-list';

const CaseStudyList = () => {

    const caseStudyItems = caseStudies.map( caseStudy => {
        console.log(caseStudy);
        return (
            <div key={caseStudy.name}>{caseStudy.name}</div>
        );
    });


    return (
        <ul>
            {caseStudyItems}
        </ul>
    );
}

export default CaseStudyList;
```

The expected number of case studies is printed out with no problem.

If however I replace the div inside of the caseStudies.map statement with the following

```
<CaseStudyItem key={caseStudy.id} caseStudy={caseStudy} />
```

I get a "Maximum Callstack size exceed error" if I add a log statement in there it shows it spitting out hundred and hundreds of items.  What would cause this?

In case its needed here is the CaseStudyItem component, which is just blank now for testing purposes.

```
import React from 'react';

const CaseStudyItem = () => {

    return (
        <div>case Study</div>
    );
}

export default CaseStudyItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making new `CaseStudyLists` inside each `CaseStudyList`. This is because you (probably) import from the wrong file:

```
import CaseStudyItem from './case-study-list';
```

should perhaps be

```
import CaseStudyItem from './case-study-item';
```

When you import like this, you can name the imported variable whatever you want, so what you though was the `CaseStudyItem` component creator was actually the `CaseStudyList` component creator.

Comment: Oh man I am dumb.  Thank you,  I was staring at this for hours and had no idea what was going on.

Comment: Don't worry, easy mistake to make.

Comment: @Cody If you don't mind, please accept the answer :)